# What is the Goodwillie calculus interpretation of Quillen's rational homotopy theory?

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, higher-algebra

$\newcommand\Spaces{\mathit{Spaces}}\newcommand\sLie{\mathit{sLie}}\DeclareMathOperator\id{id}$Let $X$ be a space. Then $\pi_\ast(X)$ is a shifted Lie algebra under the Whitehead bracket $[-,-]$. Recall Quillen showed that in the 1-connected case, the functor
$$\Spaces_{\mathbb Q} \to \sLie(\mathbb Q)$$
$$X \mapsto (\pi_\ast(X)\otimes \mathbb Q, [-,-])$$
is an equivalence. Recall also that the rationalization of the Goodwillie derivatives of the identity functor on $\Spaces$ is the shifted Lie operad $\sLie$. So the chain rule of Arone and Ching tells us that if $F: \Spaces_{\mathbb Q} \to \Spaces_{\mathbb Q}$ is a functor, then the derivatives $\partial_\ast(F)$ (a symmetric sequence in $D(\mathbb Q)$) are a module over $\partial_\ast(\id) = \sLie$.

**Question 1:** Let $X$ be a space. Can the existence of a shifted Lie algebra structure on $\pi_\ast(X) \otimes \mathbb Q$ be deduced from knowing the chain rule and the fact that $\partial_\ast(\id)\otimes \mathbb Q = \sLie_{\mathbb Q}$?

A natural guess is to look at the functor $F = ((-) \times X)_{\mathbb Q}$, but I'm a bit confused because it seems like $\pi_\ast(X) \otimes \mathbb Q$ is the first derivative of this functor — I'm not sure what to do with the higher derivatives (or the zeroth derivative for that matter).

**Question 2:** Can Quillen's theorem (that $X \mapsto (\pi_\ast(X)\otimes \mathbb Q, [-,-])$ is an equivalence) be deduced from the fact that the identity functor on $\Spaces$ is 1-analytic?

Comment: Question 2: there needs to be a differential on your lie algebra for this to yield an equivalence

Comment: @ConnorMalin Yeah, I've been really sloppy, but by $sLie(\mathbb Q)$ I secretly did mean shifted Lie algebras in rational chain complexes (the localization of spectra at the rational equivalences).

Comment: Oh I see, the functor I've described above is not actually the functor which is an equivalence

Comment: Ben Walter wrote his thesis on Goodwillie calculus in rational homotopy theory.  It doesn't exactly get at the questions you are asking, but it does many related things.  It provides an explanation for a sort of converse of 1, namely seeing that the derivatives of the identity are (shifted) coLie is immediate in the Lie model for rational homotopy types.

Comment: I have a copy of Ben's thesis if you're interested.